# Webmaster tools give 404 error on good crawlable pages

Tags: google-search-console, 404

I have seen that Webmaster tools is giving back a 404 error for the urls which are perfectly fine, like these ones:

http://www.peliculas21.com/adam-sandler/ 
http://www.peliculas21.com/robin-williams/

Why can this happen?
Should I just mark them as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When Google Webmaster tool return a 404 status code:**

When you remove a page from your site, think about whether that content is moving somewhere else, or whether you no longer plan to have that type of content on your site.

- When moving content to a new URL, redirect the old URL to the new URL—that way when users come to the old URL looking for that content, they’ll be automatically redirected to something relevant to what they were looking for.
- When you permanently remove content without intending to replace it with newer, related content, let the old URL return a 404 or 410. Currently Google treats 410s (Gone) the same as 404s (Not found).

So you shouldn't worry about it as your webpages are working fine. You just mark as fixed in Google Webmaster tool.

Comment: Generally yes, this is good advice. However, you should check the actually HTTP headers returned by the server to make sure they're actually "working" as intended. It's possible for the server to return the content the user was looking for while also returning a 404 status. So while everything will appear fine to humans, bots will think the pages are missing.